# ffmpeg live transcoding faster alternative?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, dvb

Is there any opensource alternative to `ffmpeg` and `VLC` to live video transcoding from HTTP streaming to RTMP or other?

`ffmpeg` caused my CPU (AMD 4.0GHZ 8Core) is loaded 100% with only 8 SD streams.

Thanks for help.

PS.
I think I don't need to transcode my video, I can also stream with something like http video proxy. Source is in HTTP streaming format, also I am under Linux.

Comment: Are you encoding or just re-muxing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question should be: "Is there any opensource alternative faster than ffmpeg".

And the answer is No.

If you dont need to transcode, add `-acodec copy -vcodec copy` to your command line

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` is flexible encoder you can tweak it much you like , it's up to encoding algorithm and Size VS Quality battle , I think now days X264 are more efficacy than it was before , the important tweaks with ffmpeg to speedup encoding is `-preset` the default is `medium` you can use `fast` or `faster` and watch the quality of your output video . I have live steaming video and I use this command

```
 ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -thread_queue_size 32768 -re -i "http://sorce" -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -break_non_keyframes 1 -profile:v high444 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 260k -acodec aac -b:a 32k -map_metadata -1 -s 480x360 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/live
```

That for very low quality video ,

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -thread_queue_size 32768 -re -i "http://source" -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -break_non_keyframes 1 -b:v 665k -profile:v high444 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -acodec aac -b:a 32k -map_metadata -1 -s 854x480 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/live
```

you will get better quality and viewable picture when  increase `-b:v` value .
so it's up to you preferred network you can get much higher video quality with less CPU usage.